# connect to sql "server group" with php to run query over multiple databases

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to an MSSQL Server group with PHP and action a select query over a view
. I can connect & pull results from the server
. I can connect & pull results from a DB

With MSSQL under registered servers (top left) you can create a new server group and add existing databases as a server registration this allows for a single query to be run over multiple databases. I cant find any information on how to connect to this from PHP.

FYI:-Setting Server Group: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTz3OZKTdMg

I have also tried creating a view in each database then in one database creating a view that joins each of the views together it works in management studio but i get an error form PHP "Undefined Index"

I.e
db1:

```
Create View ffa
```

db2:

```
Create view ffa
```

:dblook

```
create view ffa as select * From db1.ffa union all select * From db2.ffa
```

Then php to look at dblook.ffa
I get a connection but "Undefined Index" error?

I have both SQL and Express currently testing on Express
I would prefer the connecting to server group option (seems a lot faster in management studio)
But happy to try any other solution

Comment: Where is your tried code??

Comment: in the middle it was meant to be three little examples i.e. db1:, db2: and dblook it looks horrible sorry, i'll try and fix it up again

Comment: Could you share the PHP code you are using behind this? Normally a view just returns a result just like a table. The `undefined index` is mostlikely just you misspelling a case-senstive columnname

Comment: It looks like there is a requirement for the indexes on all tables to be the same. Are they _exactly_ the same?

Answer (score 2):

The server group is just a logical way to group Servers in the GUI.  It's not a function of the SQL Server database engine.

What you are referring to is partitioned views which falls under the concept of Federated Database Servers.

- [Federated Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187075%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Partitioned Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Basically, using Linked Servers, you create views on each database servers that union multiple servers together.  A load balancer can then point to any database server.  This only happens on the read requests as other CRUD operations require some type of routing.